# setTableHeaderView removes the cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIView I inserted inside the UITableView in my Storyboard.

I hide the view by using `[self.tableview setTableHeaderView nil] in`viewDidLoad` which the app loads the view correctly.

However when I want to show the view again, by using 
`[self.tableview setTableHeaderView self.headerView]` it removes all the UITableView cells and replaces it with just the HeaderView.

How do I restore the headerview without removing the cells?

Thanks!

Comment: do you know the song of Eddy Grant — «♫ Gimme Code Jo'anna ♪» ?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Nope, but I am happy to post some code. I am not sure what code I need to post as most of the setup is done in Interface Builder and basically it's the `[self.tableView setTableHeaderView self.headerView]` is what i'm having trouble with.

Comment: it might be important WHERE u do `[self.tableView setTableHeaderView self.headerView]`

Comment: @vikingosegundo I am just putting it in a `(void)buttonPressed` method that is executed when I press a `UIBarButton` on the navigation controller. I call `[self.tableView setTableHeaderView self.headerView]` and then call `[self.tableView reloadData]`. The buttonPressed method just toggles between `[self.tableView setTableHeaderView self.headerView]` and `[self.tableView setTableHeaderView nil]`

Comment: that sounds sane. so your problem must lay elsewhere. you will ahve to post any code related to the tableview

Comment: Is there data loaded when you call reloadData after setting the header? I would also try calling [self.tableView setNeedsLayout] after setting the header view.

Comment: @sixthcent Yes, there is data.I have a singular cell, but it's just swapping between the cell and the headerview. I tried setNeedsLayout, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Turned out that I had the view of the xib bound to the view of the controller vs binding it to the property pointing to headerview